# Avoid XSS attacks on Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, xss, antixsslibrary

**I'm currently editing an existing web application where I need to improve the codes to protect it from XSS attacks, I researched about it, but most of the articles I saw was for raw HTML and also they don't give a lot of example. I was thinking that I may just need to use some anti-xss libraries, but I'm not sure I'm fairly new to Angular JS so I would like to get some insights first before changing anything**

Here are some of the code lines that are said to be unsafe.
[image]

**Here are sample code snippets of the first 3.**

Line 1663:

[image]

Line 1686:

[image]

Line 1836:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an article specific to my case, but the link bellow gives an idea on how to remediate this on a basic level.

https://vitalflux.com/angular-top-10-security-best-practices-vis-vis-security-risks/